# Количество последовательностей

Tags: комбинаторика, динамический-анализ, c++

Помогите решить такую задачу: нужно посчитать количество последовательностей длины n из 0,1,2, в которых не менее a0 нулей, a1 единиц и a2 двоек. Числа n, a0, a1, a2 вводятся с клавиатуры

Comment: @Gsgbug, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

так же переименуйте  a0, a1, a2 в x,y,z (дабы не было путаницы)

так же непонятно по длине последовательности, длина N это строго? то есть числа 10,11,2,1,222 при N =10, будут принадлежать последовательности? или нет?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat Длина N - строгая, причем надо посчитать количество тех последовательностей, в каждой из которых хотя бы x нулей, y единиц и z двоек, например если вводятся данные N = 10, X = 5, Y = 2, Z = 4, то таких последовательностей нет, потому что нижних границ (X+Y+Z = 5+2+4=11) больше, чем указанная длина последовательности (10). Или, например, если ввести данные N=3, X=1, Y=1, Z=1, то ответом будет 6 последовательностей: 012 021 102 120 210 201

Comment: @Gsgbug, ясно, вроде ничего сложного, главный вопрос:

есть ли ограничения по памяти\времени ?

просто если нет то можно сделать тупо перебором с проверкой, если нужно выполнять за константное время то нужно погуглить теорию вероятности на тему ограничений (точно помню что там есть какой-то способ)

Comment: я думаю, что эту задачу можно решить сугубо математически. Только нужно разделить на три подзадачи, в зависимости от соотношения a0+a1+a2 <> N.

Если они равны, тогда это просто произведение перестановок. Ведь вначале можно разложить все 0, потом по пустым местам все 1 и для двоек использовать только один вариант (мест то им хватит впритык).

Если a0+a1+a2 > N, то появляются "свободные места", и на эти места можно заполнить 0, 1 или 2. И это как бы отдельная задача на перестановки.

Третью подзадачу решать не нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim Рассуждал точно также, но появляется проблема со свободными местами, например последовательность 12012 может быть посчитана дважды, если a0 = a1 = a2 = 1, N = 5, т.к с одной стороны мы можем выбрать перестановку 120_ _ и свободные места заполнить как 12, а можем выбрать перестановку _ _012, а свободные места заполнить также 12, тогда одна и та же последовательность будет посчитана дважды. Не понимаю, как считать общее количество в таком случае

Comment: нужно рассуждать по простому. Пусть у нас на один разряд больше. Туда можно вставить одну цифру. В любом случае у нас будет *3 вариантов. Можно попробовать порассуждать таким же образом дальше.

Answer (score 1):

При достаточно малых размерностях задачу можно решить и без динамики.
Количество нулей должно быть в пределах от a0 до n-a1-a2, единиц - от a1 до n-a0-a2, двоек - от a2 до n-a0-a1. Учитывая это, можно пройтись двойным циклом по количеству нулей c0 и количеству единиц c1 (количество двоек считать как c2=n-c0-c1) и суммировать количество последовательностей, в которых ровно c0, c1 и c2 нулей, единиц и двоек, соответственно:

```
res = 0;
for (c0 = a0; c0 <= n - a1 - a2; c0++)
{
  for (c1 = a1; c1 <= n - a0 - a2; c1++)
  {
    c2 = n - c0 - c1;
    // можно не проверять дальнейшие варианты, т.к. увеличение c1 приведет к уменьшению c2
    if (c2 < a2) break;
    res += f(c0, c1, c2);
  }
}
```

А подзадачу для конкретных c0, c1, c2 можно решить математически при помощи комбинаторных формул. Сначала находим число последовательностей длины c0+c1, содержащих c0 нулей и c1 единиц - это число раскладок мест, куда можно поместить единицы. Аналогично умножаем на число раскладок мест, куда поместить после этого двойки. Это шаблонная задача, посмотрите в интернете.
Если очень точный ответ не требуется, то можно считать факториалы приближенно по формуле Стирлинга.